# auto start telegram bot in code anywhere

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot

i install telegram anti spam python bot on codeanywhere but that bot Turns off every 2 hours.
Is there a command to turn the robot back on after turning off?

Comment: Maybe just `/start`? To me (and obviously also others, like @Sean), your problem is hard to understand. Please ask more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Use loop inside code.

```
while True:
    // runbot
```